# Gedit problems while launching in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, launcher, gedit

I have been using Gedit since the 14 years without any problem. But recently, it does not launch and when I ran it from the terminal I got this error message-

```
gedit

(gedit:2381): GLib-GIO-ERROR **: 17:52:55.834: Settings schema 'org.gnome.gedit.plugins.time' is not installed

Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
```

I had installed the plug-in using this command - `sudo apt-get install -y gedit-plugins`
Kindly guide me as to what might have gone wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This gschema file is contained in [different package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&arch=any&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=org.gnome.gedit.plugins.time). Reinstall it with

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gedit-common
```